# ExactTarget Query Activity Data View - Correct Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, documentation

I am in the process of writing numerous query activities and have written a simple SQL for getting bounce events.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, EventDate, BounceType FROM _Bounce
```

When checking the syntax of this query, I am informed:

> The query syntax is invalid
>
> - _Bounce is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

However, the documentation for [Bounce](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_bounce/) states that the data view name is `_Bounce`.

Additionally, the [Query](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) example documentation doesn't seem to maintain a constant capitalization of table names/attributes compared to the data views' documentation.

Does ExactTarget provide any accurate documentation of the schema of their data views?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to contact SFMC Support to have the System Data Views enabled.

Transact-SQL is not case-sensitive in the [SFMC SQL Server 2005 environment](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

Answer (score -1):

Replace _Bounce with ent._bounce and it should work

Comment: SQL Server is not case-sensitive.